# Make use of custom tag to avoid CFM files mingled with lots of HTML markups?

Tags: coldfusion

Have you had any success with uses of custom tag for view that increase maintainability?

Does use of custom tag have any benefit of using basic `<cfinclude>`?

Any custom tag you have written before that increase HTML maintainability?

Thanks

Comment: Any other example that dramatically improves maintainability over `<cfinclude>`? thanks

Comment: Mango blog uses CT for views pretty nicely http://www.mangoblog.org

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes and Yes.

Custom tags are awesome for separating out reusable HTML elements. The advantages are that they are scope-safe, and you can pass arguments into them to change their behavior, which you can't do with `cfinclude`. You can even create nested tags that change their behavior based on their parents. Most of my HTML layouts in ColdFusion look something like this:

```
<cf_layout>
    <cf_head title="My Page>
    <!--- Some local head stuff ---->
    </cf_head>

    <cf_content>
        Lots of stuff goes here.
    </cf_content>
</cf_layout>
```

This is obviously greatly simplified, but I can change the entire layout of a site by changing the custom tag, or even changing the custom tag folder (think dynamic `this.customTagPaths` for swapping out layouts.

Custom Tags don't get enough love. Embrace them, and enjoy :).

Here's another example of something I do:

```
<cfset arOrders = OrderService.getOrders() />

<table>
    <cfloop array="#arOrders#" index="currentOrder">
        <cf_orderrow order="#currentOrder#" />
    </cfloop>
</table>
```

My `OrderRow` custom tag handles all of the display for displaying a row for an order in a table. This includes add/edit/delete buttons, calculations that have to happen, conditions that must be me to change the display. I can display an order row anywhere I want in an admin area. On the customer details page, on a page showing all orders in a certain time period. It makes no difference. My users know that any place they see a row describing an order, it will look just as they expect it to.

Here are a few more concrete examples of small custom tags I use across multiple applications.

**cf_jquery**

This includes jQuery and jQueryUI in a page, but only if no other template in the application has already added jQuery on this request. This allows me to build multiple jQuery parts to a page, and no matter what order I call them in, I'll always know that jQuery has been added to the head of the document only once.

```
<cfif thisTag.ExecutionMode EQ "end" AND (NOT StructKeyExists(Request, "JQueryInited") OR Request.JQueryInited EQ False)>
    <cfparam name="Attributes.IncludeUI" default="False" />
    <cfparam name="Request.jQueryUIInited" default="False" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <cfif Attributes.IncludeUI AND Request.jQueryUIInited IS False>
        <link href="/shared/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <cfset Request.jQueryUIInited = True />
    </cfif>
    <cfset Request.JQueryInited = True />
</cfif>
```

I even build tags for small information that I know will be used throughout the application in multiple places, like this `cf_contact` tag:

```
<cfif thisTag.ExecutionMode EQ "end">
    <cfparam name="Attributes.Phone" default="xxx.xxx.xxxx" />
    <cfparam name="Attributes.Email" default="me@you.com" />
    <cfparam name="Attributes.EmailName" default="Email Support" />
    <h2 style="font: bold 12px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-bottom: 0;">Contact Us</h2>
    <p style="text-align: left; margin-top: 0;"><cfoutput>#Attributes.Phone#</cfoutput><br />
    <cfoutput><a href="mailto:#Attributes.Email#">#Attributes.EmailName#</a></cfoutput></p>
</cfif>
```

Why make a tag for something so small? Why not? If I style all my contact information the same throughout an application (and I should, so users can easily identify things), then I can make a tag for it just as easily as I can make an include. If I decide I want some other programmatic behavior to happen in there, my app is already set up to use it.

**cf_timeblock**

This custom tag shows a set of select lists for choosing a time block (hh:mm tt). I use this all over an application dealing with scheduling, so I have a tag that will allow me to display a block for a time, and I can send in which values should be pre-selected (I'm missing validation for the attributes, but just pretend it's there for now):

```
<cfif thisTag.ExecutionMode EQ "end">
    <cfsilent>
        <!--- Get Time Blocks --->
        <cfset TimeBlocks = Application.DAO.getTimeQueries() />
    </cfsilent>
    <select name="hour" style="width: auto; float: none;">
        <cfoutput query="TimeBlocks.Hours">
            <option value="#TimeBlocks.Hours.Value#"<cfif TimeBlocks.Hours.Value EQ Attributes.Hour> selected="selected"</cfif>>
                #TimeBlocks.Hours.Value#
            </option>
        </cfoutput>
    </select>:<select name="min" style="width: auto; float: none;">
        <cfoutput query="TimeBlocks.Mins">
            <option value="#TimeBlocks.Mins.Value#"<cfif TimeBlocks.Mins.Value EQ Attributes.Min> selected="selected"</cfif>>
                #TimeBlocks.Mins.Value#
            </option>
        </cfoutput>
    </select>
    <select name="mer" style="width: auto; float: none;">
        <cfoutput query="TimeBlocks.Mer">
            <option value="#TimeBlocks.Mer.Value#"<cfif TimeBlocks.Mer.Value EQ FORM.mer> selected="selected"</cfif>>
                #TimeBlocks.Mer.Value#
            </option>
        </cfoutput>
    </select>
</cfif>
```

I use tons more than this, but they're all very application/object specific. Just about any time I start to pull something out into an include, or if I find myself copying a piece of display logic from one page to another, I start thinking about how I can push that code into a custom tag.

Here are a few more examples of custom tag libraries that I find useful.

- [cfUniform](http://www.quackfuzed.com/demos/cfUniForm/)
- [Ben Nadel's POI Custom Tags](http://www.bennadel.com/projects/poi-utility.htm)

Comment: I agree with Dan Short's answer, I still use Custom Tags. Above and beyond Dan's answer, Railo uses CFC Custom Tags as well as regular custom tags to create built-in-tags / built-in-functions so you can bake your own tags / functions into Railo.

Comment: also, do you usually use cf_, cfimport prefix=, or cfmodule to invoke custom tag?

Comment: It really does not matter if you use "cf_", cf module or cfimport, the custom tags will work the same. Personally, I have come to really like the cfimport method.

Comment: I use `cf_` whenever possible, because they're server-wide. My issue with `cfimport` is that you have to use it on every page, and it doesn't cascade down through the entire request. If I have places where I have very specialized use of the tags, then I'll fallback on `cfimport` provided those custom tags aren't used outside of that narrow scope...

Comment: @Dan hmm, doesn't cf_ relies on .cfm in the same level?  Wouldn't u end up with.. a folder with lots of custom tags?

Comment: @Dan, other then the 2 examples, do u have anything more concrete or maybe an opensource project that uses that approach?  I still find it not that much more powerful then cfinclude.

Comment: Nope, you can put tags in any CustomTag path mapping in the cf admin, or in any path defined by `this.customTagPaths` (which can take more than one path). According to the live docs (which leaves out this.customTagPaths), You must store custom tag pages in any one of the following: The same directory as the calling page; The cfusion\CustomTags directory; A subdirectory of the cfusion\CustomTags directory; A directory that you specify in the ColdFusion Administrator. http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=reuseCode_2.html

Comment: Also, you can add as many subfolders as you like to organize things, and CF will just ignore the folder structure. You get to organize it, and just make sure that all your filenames are unique, even in subdirectories.

Comment: I'll post an example of one I use tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

One example missing from Dan's otherwise excellent efforts is the very powerful but under-utilised capabilities custom tags have to iterate over enclosed content:

```
<!--- loop.cfm --->
<cfif (THISTAG.ExecutionMode EQ "Start")>
    <cfparam name="attributes.index" type="variablename">
    <cfparam name="attributes.iterations" type="integer">

    <cfset variables.index = 1>
    <cfset caller[attributes.index] = variables.index>
<cfelse>
    <cfset variables.index = variables.index + 1>
    <cfif variables.index lte attributes.iterations>
        <cfset caller[attributes.index] = variables.index>
        <cfexit method="loop">
    <cfelse>
        <cfexit method="exittag">
    </cfif>
</cfif>

<!--- testLoop.cfm --->
<cf_loop iterations="10" index="i">
    <cfoutput>[#i#]</cfoutput>Hello World<br />
</cf_loop>
```

The one caveat I would offer for using custom tags is that I have heard they are prone to leaking memory (I cannot substaniate this), so if using them on a heavy-traffic site, I'd load test them thoroughly before going live with them.

Comment: Absolutely. I use a date loop custom tag from Ben Nadel all the time :). I also absolutely love *nesting* custom tags, and creating building blocks for more complicated behaviors. There's a lot of power there once you get into it.

Comment: I'm sorry, how's that different from regular cfloop with from, to, index, step?

Comment: Check http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1689-Advanced-ColdFusion-Custom-Tags-With-Ben-Nadel-Video-Presentation-.htm and http://www.bennadel.com/blog/927-Generated-Content-And-Looping-ColdFusion-Custom-Tags.htm. Also, http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=active&source=hp&q=custom+tag+site:bennadel.com&pbx=1&oq=custom+tag+site:bennadel.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=4679l5128l1l5457l2l2l0l0l0l0l86l152l2l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=17d332deb5615e0d&biw=1255&bih=1068

Comment: Henry, that example *isn't* different from just a CFLOOP (in fact it's probably pretty much how CFLOOP is implemented, in a very cut down way, and in CFML instead of Java.  Remember CFML is just a JSP taglib, after all).  It's just the most minimal example of a looping custom tag I could think of. I created it specifically that way to demonstrate how looping in a custom tag works without any unnecessary clutter.  The point was to demonstrate the *technique*, not any specific implementation.